# parkingStateChanged signal emitted error

Tags: omnet++, veins

I tried to stop vehicles using `setStop` command in `TraciCommandInterface.cc` file.

I have successfully implemented the command, but as soon as the vehicle stops I get an error saying:

> "Undeclared Signal emitted(parkingStateChanged) @signal missing from
>   ned file.

[image: This is the error that appears].

How do I solve this?

To solve this error I added a signal as `parkingStateChanged` in my `traciScenarioManagerLaunchd.xml` file and in the corresponding header file I defined it as `simsignal_t parkingStateChanged` and in the `.cc` file in `initialize()` method I wrote

```
this->parkingStateChanged=registerSignal("parkingStateChanged");
```

But this implementation does not work and I get the same error. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you added the signal to `traciScenarioManagerLaunchd.xml` or did you mean `.ned`?